# using $_POST in if statement

Tags: php, html

Suppose I have the html code below:

```
<FORM name="myForm" action="confirmsold.php" method="post" onsubmit="return validateFormCash()">
    <table border=0 width="300" cellspacing=1 cellpadding=3 bgcolor="#353535" align="center">
    <tr>
    <br>

    <tr>
        <td bgcolor="#ffffff" colspan=2 width="30%"><b>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Input Payment Details (CASH)<b></td> 
        </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td bgcolor="#ffffff">Payment Type:</td>
        <td bgcolor="#ffffff"><input type="text" name="paytype" value="Cash" disabled></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td bgcolor="#ffffff">Date Sold:</td>
        <td bgcolor="#ffffff"><input type="date" name="date" value="<?php echo date('Y-m-d'); ?>"></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td bgcolor="#ffffff">Cash Amount:</td>
        <td bgcolor="#ffffff"><INPUT type="TEXT" name="cashamount" size="10" maxlength="9" onkeypress="if ( isNaN( String.fromCharCode(event.keyCode) )) return false;"></INPUT></td>
    </tr>

    <td bgcolor="#ffffff" colspan=2 align="center">
        <INPUT type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
        </td>
    </tr></form>
```

As you can see, it has a default value of "CASH". Now this will be submitted to a php page with an if statement:

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST' && $_POST['paytype'] == 'Cash') {
```

This is the Javascript im using for the form:

```
function validateFormCash() {
    var x = document.forms["myForm"]["cashamount"].value;
    if (x == null || x == "") {
        alert("Please input Cash Amount");
        return false;
    }
}
```

But the page will return an error saying undefined paytype, what am I missing here? Anyone please help.

Thank you

Comment: Do you have the submit and paytype input in the same form?

Comment: Where is the `Form`? What type are you using(GET/POST)?

Comment: sorry, already edited my post, kindly check

Comment: Could you show us your JS, it seems you might be manipulating the data in the JS

Comment: edited my post showing my JS

Comment: Could you do a `var_dump($_POST);` on the php page you submit to? And then include the outcome here, (you need to submit the form once.)

Comment: Wait, is the input field disabled?! Please show us your ***REAL*** code.

Comment: Since your input is disabled, `$_REQUEST` will not catch it. You can write something like in my example and it will work.

Comment: ok i think i get it.. yes input field is "disabled". and i set value="Cash". And im using that in the if statement in my php page. but it gives me undefined "paytype"

Comment: And have you tried my suggestion? That one with `if` conditional? It should work fine since this field must be enabled.

Comment: use `Readonly` instead of disabled, disabled prevents the field from being submitted.

Comment: Oh WOW! readonly worked! so the only problem was i was using "disabled". that took me 3hrs. Thanks a bunch Epodax. and thanks guys for the support!!

Comment: Hi. If this or any answer has solved your question please consider accepting it by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this, though.

Answer (score -1):

Write this in `if` conditional:

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST' && $_POST['submit']) {
```

<s>To be able to catch this `$_POST`, you have to put input field in form. For example:</s>

```
<form action="" method="POST">
    <!-- some HTML here, including <table> tag -->
    <tr>
        <td bgcolor="#ffffff">Payment Type:</td>
        <td bgcolor="#ffffff"><input type="text" name="paytype" value="Cash"></td>
    </tr><tr>
<td bgcolor="#ffffff" colspan=2 align="center">
        <INPUT type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
        </td>
    </tr>
    <!-- Some more HTML here, including </table> end tag -->
</form>
```

Comment: @KimLo Did you write `<?` or `<?php` at the start? This might be an issue. I also tested and for me this form works.

Comment: Hi the $_POST['paytype'] must also be evaluated, how do i do this?

Comment: @KimLo Glad to hear it worked for you. But for some random reason someone downvoted me.